# Angular2 : Add textbox entry to a span on click of button

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am totally new to Angular2 and would need your help for the below exercise. I need to add the entry from the textbox to the span on HTML. I have been requested to make changes only in the .ts file

I am not able to understand what needs to be added in the AddMore to ensure the entry from textbox is added on click of button beside the checkbox. **Please help**.

**Angular.component.html:**

```
<h1>Fresco PLAY Activity Tracker</h1>
<div>
    <div *ngFor="let todo of todos; let i=index" class="todoItem">
        <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="todo.done" />
        <span [ngClass]="{'checked': todo.done}">{{i+1}}. {{ todo.desc }}</span>
    </div>
    <span *ngIf="todos.length == 0">No Activities to track! Start by adding one</span><br/>
    <input id="newTodo" type="text" [(ngModel)]="newToDo">
    <span *ngIf="error" style="color:red;">Please enter an activity!</span>
    <br/>
    <button id="addActivity" (click)="addMore()">Add an Activity!</button>
    <button id="clearAll" (click)="clearAll()">Clear All</button>
</div>
```

**App.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  //Define your variables done,todos,newToDo,newToDoObj,error
 public done: boolean;
  public todos : any;
  public newToDo : string;
  public newToDoObj : any;
  public error : boolean;
  //Define your constructor here with todos as [] ,newToDo as '' and error as false
constructor(){
    this.todos = [];
    this.newToDo = '';
    this.error = false;

  }
  //Define your addMore function here
  //Define your clearAll function here
addMore(){

}
clearAll(){

}
}
```

Comment: you need to create a new 'todo' object and push it into this.todos

Answer (score 3):

Angular Activity Tracker :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  public done: boolean;
  public todos : any;
  public newToDo : string;
  public newToDoObj : any;
  public error : boolean;
  //public TODOS : Array;
  constructor(){
    this.todos = [];
    this.newToDo = '';
    this.error = false;
  }
  addMore(){
   this.todos.push({done : true, item : this.newToDo});
  }
  clearAll(){
  this.todos = [];
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`public newToDo: string` is where your input's value is. 
`public todos: any` (should be `public todos: Array<string>` or `public todos: string[]`) hold all of your tasks which has been already created.

`addMore()` function is being called after clicking on `addActivity` button. So now in `addMore()` function you should take `newToDo` value and push it to `todos` using `push()` method.

```
addMore() {
this.todos.push(this.newToDo);
}
```